# enable compression in TimeScaleDB hypertable - invalid column name

Tags: sql, postgresql, timescaledb, hypertable

When I try and enable compression on my TimeScale DB hypertable using this query:

```
ALTER TABLE public."Session" SET (
  timescaledb.compress,
  timescaledb.compress_segmentby = 'AssetId'
);
```

I get the following error:

```
ERROR:  column "assetid" does not exist
HINT:  The timescaledb.compress_segmentby option must reference a valid column.
SQL state: 42601
```

All I can say is that `AssetId` is a valid column in the `Session` table. I'm not sure what else to try.

Is anybody familiar with this error and could offer a solution please?

Thank you

Comment: Not sure but a first guess would be `timescaledb.compress_segmentby = '"AssetId"'`? But just a wild guess  Otherwise can you provide the table schema?

Comment: Ok that appears to have worked.. feel free to answer the question and I'll accept.

I remember trying the quotes the other way around. I don't remember PG being this awkward last time around.. anyway thank you a lot.

Comment: I don't remember when you have to quote mixed case column names, maybe it was case-sensitive file systems?  Anyhow. Happy it worked. Let me make it an answer 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes Postgresql requires the case-sensitive version of the name and therefore the column name was to be quoted.

That said, all you do is to double-quote the name inside the passed string:
`timescaledb.compress_segmentby = '"AssetId"'`